# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection. WCF with azure Error

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, azure, objectcontext

**Edit: Got it sorted, The table had foreign keys that weren't being addressed. Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post an answer to it this close to asking the question**

I'm making a windows phone application that gets information from a database held on Windows Azure, I'm using a WCF connection to do so.

But when I debug and locally call the service I get the following error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I'm using code that I adapted from http://mobile.dzone.com/news/how-use-wcf-services-access-0 (the  LoginUser section) The code from that site works fine but, like I said, mine causes that error.

Here's my code:

```
    public Product GetProduct(String Barcode)
    {
        string query = @"SELECT value Product FROM AzureDBEntities.Products AS Product WHERE Product.barcode = @Barcode";
        ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter("Barcode", Barcode);

        using (var context = new AzureDBEntities())
        {
            ObjectQuery<Product> results = context.CreateQuery<Product>(query, parameter);

            foreach (Product result in results)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Any Ideas What I've done wrong? Many Thanks.

Comment: WCFServiceWebRole1.dll!WCFServiceWebRole1.Product.Producer1.get() Line 1028 + 0x34 bytes

is this what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the entity to an instance of your ObjectContext through it's detach method. That will destroy your navigable collections, but you won't have to turn off lazy loading.

```
public Product GetProduct(String Barcode)
{
    string query = @"SELECT value Product FROM AzureDBEntities.Products AS Product WHERE Product.barcode = @Barcode";
    ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter("Barcode", Barcode);

    using (var context = new AzureDBEntities())
    {
        ObjectQuery<Product> results = context.CreateQuery<Product>(query, parameter);

        foreach (Product result in results)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                context.Detach(result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comment on your answer you state that the erro is caused by the following: **WCFServiceWebRole1.dll!WCFServiceWebRole1.Product.Producer1.get()**

This indicates that something is trying to access the Producer property on your Product entity (probably caused by WCF serializaiton). Could you try turning off lazy loading and proxy creation on your context?

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
    context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```